# What does the handover for a mascot should have?

Tags: illustration, graphic-styles

We hired an artist to create a mascot for us in 2D.

The idea is the handover should help further designers in creating all kinds of designs, which can be a comic strip or an ad-campaign using the handover data.

As the artist is not that well versed with these pointers neither do we, We seek to find out how to approach this problem.

Should we define multiple scenarios of Standing and Sitting positions, and get them developed?

Or Should we separate individual body elements and get multiple angles for the same?

Please suggest.

Comment: What does your contract stipulate? I mean its a little late to ask the artist to change scope of the project after its been agreed to that is unless you pay him by the hour (which does not seem like best use of your or artits time). Anyway its not like we know your needs or what other artits you employ to do the imagery. Anyway you can probably see now why mascots are seldom used.

Comment: We are adding an extra amount to the contract with the artist, so the handover can be smoother. A definite answer would be useful. The other designers are juniors, and are expected to plug and play the structure made.

Comment: It is harder to find a useful resource as well.